# If statement in accordion

Tags: javascript, if-statement

How if statement can open and close this accordion, if max-height = 0 ?

```
var accordions = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");

for (var i = 0; i < accordions.length; i++) {
  accordions[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle('is-open');

    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

this is the HTML code

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Accordions</h1>
    <button class="accordion">Accordian #1</button>
    <div class="accordion-content">lorem</div>
    <button class="accordion">Accordian #2</button>
    <div class="accordion-content">lorem</div>
    <button class="accordion">Accordian #3</button>
    <div class="accordion-content">lorem</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: `console.log(content.style.maxHeight)`

Comment: explain if statement in this code? there is no condition in this if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (content.style.maxHeight)` is equivalent to:

`if (content.style.maxHeight == true)`

In your code the condition is `false` if `content.style.maxHeight` has the value of empty string (`""`) because empty string is falsy in JavaScript.

Some other falsy values:

```
if(false)
if(null)
if(undefined)
if(0)
if(NaN)
if('')
if("")
```

Comment: how content.style.maxheight = null can close the content?

Comment: @MostafaKhan, what do you mean by "can close the content?". `null` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: Thank you @Mamun, I got my answer